# KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'OpenIdConnect.Code.RedirectUri' was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using vue cli middleware with identityserver with Hybrid Flow.
On Ajax call I have redirected manually to identityprovider as below.

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                 {
                     if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                     {
                         if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                         {
                             context.ProtocolMessage.State = options.StateDataFormat.Protect(context.Properties);
                             context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                             context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.ProtocolMessage.CreateAuthenticationRequestUrl();
                         }
                         context.HandleResponse();
                     }
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 };
```

On callback from identityserver I am getting below error.

**KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'OpenIdConnect.Code.RedirectUri' was not present in the dictionary.**

Below is the callstack.

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)**

What's wrong?

I am using identityserver from below repo.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4

My forked repo (with above code)

https://github.com/hnviradiya/asp-net-core-vue-starter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = redirectContext =>
                      {
                          if (redirectContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                          {
                              if (redirectContext.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                              {
                                  redirectContext.Properties.RedirectUri = $"{redirectContext.Request.Scheme}://{redirectContext.Request.Host}{redirectContext.Request.PathBase}";
                                  redirectContext.Properties.Items.Add(OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey, redirectContext.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
                                  redirectContext.ProtocolMessage.State = options.StateDataFormat.Protect(redirectContext.Properties);
                                  redirectContext.Response.StatusCode =   (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                                  redirectContext.Response.Headers["Location"] = redirectContext.ProtocolMessage.CreateAuthenticationRequestUrl();
                              }
                              redirectContext.HandleResponse();
                          }
                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                      };
```

Comment: I couldn't thank you more! you saved may day with this answer + the previous one about the missing state. Thank you so much!